# "Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements" in hibernate when annotating a ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, hibernate

I've tried annotating a property accessor whose return value is a map as follows:

```
@MapKeyColumn(name="parameter_name")
@ElementCollection
public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Serializable> getParameterValues()
```

This is in accordance with the hibernate user guide (section 2.2.5.3.4.). However, I get:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: ConfigurationParameterBag.parameterValues
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:324)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1723)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:796)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:707)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1398)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateDropSchemaScript(Configuration.java:1002)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:130)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:92)
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Check out the topic 6.1. Persistent collections on this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html) .

From the link, 
Hibernate requires that persistent collection-valued fields be declared as an interface type. The actual interface might be `java.util.Set, java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Map, java.util.SortedSet, java.util.SortedMap` or anything you like ("anything you like" means you will have to write an implementation of org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType.)

Comment: Thanks @kalatta it helped me :)